# jquery set div width fails in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, width

I have the following code and it works correctly in FF and IE8 but fails in IE 7 anyone have an idea or hack

```
    if ($("#midRight:contains('Quick Links')").length == 0) {
  $("#midCenter").css({'width':'298px'});
 }
```

html is basic

```
    <div id="midRight">
bunch of text
</div>
```

the starting css is

```
#midRight {width:440px;}
```

IE7's javascript error is "Object doesn't support this property or method.  BTW if I throw an alert in BEFORE the width change it works fine. If I move the alert to after the width change it never fires so at least I know that the conditional statement works right in IE7 just not the change of width.

Comment: Please add more details such as: HTML code, what do you mean by it fails?

Comment: Which bit fails - the if() or setting the width?

Comment: Need more HTML and the CSS you have for #midCenter as it is before the jQuery modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#midCenter").css({width:298});
```

Comment: Either this, or $("#midCenter").css('width, '298px');

Comment: very strange I thought I had tried all possible combinations but turns out removing the quotes and the px from the value solved the problem.

$("#midCenter").css({'width':298});

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in the way IE7 handles setting the width with CSS.  Does it work any better if you set the width directly?

```
if ($("#midRight:contains('Quick Links')").length == 0) {
    $("#midCenter").width(298);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the DOM to finish loading? Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    if ($("#midRight:contains('Quick Links')").length == 0)
      $("#midCenter").css({'width': 298});
});
```